# Select statements cannot return data to a client

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting an error of not being able to return data to a client when trying to create this function, I just want to know how to do the following as simple as it is by querying a table and then checking the @@ROWCOUNT and setting the bit value based on the results, how can I do this without getting too complex?

```
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Set @sDup to False
    DECLARE @sDup BIT = 0   

    --check allDataTemp
    SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN ON tbl8 WHERE fld1 = @val1 and fld2 = @val2 
                and fld3 = @val4

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END 

    --check allDataTemp2
    SELECT * FROM tbl2 

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END

    SELECT * FROM tbl3 

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @sDup
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to select the data and it's trying to output the results of that select when it's only expecting a BIT value to be returned. Please re-try with your query like so:

```
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Set @sDup to False
    DECLARE @sDup BIT = 0   

    --check allDataTemp
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END 

    --check allDataTemp2
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl3) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @sDup
END
```

A slightly more condensed version of the above which maintains the same short circuit logic would look like this:

```
BEGIN
    -- Set @sDup to False
    DECLARE @sDup BIT = 0

    -- Collect Data and perform logic
    SET @sDup = (CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1) > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2) > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl3) > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END)

    --Return Value
    RETURN @sDup
END
```

Comment: The only issue of doing it that way is that my queries are actually a lot more complex than one line, with multiple joins and predicates, I provided the bare-bone structure of what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Set @sDup to False
    DECLARE @sDup BIT = 0   

    --check allDataTemp


    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl1)
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END 

    --check allDataTemp2 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl2)
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END



    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl3)
        BEGIN
            SET @sDup = 1
            RETURN @sDup
        END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @sDup
```

Since you are only checking of existence of any rows , using `EXISTS` with `*` will give you the best performance as it will stop execution and returns True as soon as it gets the 1st hit,

Answer (score 0):

You create a count for each table, set a variable of every total and then only one if checking if any of the variables or more than 0 then return 1